# Detect CSS3 with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, browser-detection

Is there a way to detect whether a browser supports CSS3 transitions (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc..) with JQuery?

Comment: `-webkit` and `-moz` are not CSS3. They are "vendor prefixes" which denote that the feature in question is either only partially supported or that the specification is incomplete. Many of the features which use these vendor prefixes are indeed part of the CSS3 spec, but equally many CSS3 features don't require vendor prefixes in the current browser versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Modernizr css rule](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-css):

```
.csstransitions {
}
```

You can also use [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to achieve full hardware acceleration when possible, falling back to jQuery-based animation otherwise.

Comment: I like the look of Isotope too

Comment: modernizr for ONE feature to detect !? are u serious?

Answer (score 0):

[You can go for **Modernizr** to detect those as well as many other features you want to detect.](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Note: You could also download custom version of Modernizr for the features you want to detect.

Comment: Modernizr to detect one feature?